# Highcharts, highslide and ReportViewer

Tags: highcharts, highslide

I'm using a column chart (Highcharts), in my serie, event click and I have this:

```
var name = this.category;
var url='../Graphics/VtnPopup.aspx?cat='+name;
$.get(url, function (data) { 
hs.htmlExpand(null, { 
pageOrigin: { 
x: 50, 
y: 50 
}, 
headingText: name, 
maincontentText: data 
});
```

But in VtnPopup I have a reportViewer, so when the highslide open I cant see the report, I think its maybe by the type of "maincontentText", have you any idea to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t use the Highslide `maincontent` method if you want to open a specific url in the popup. You have to use the Highslide iframe popup - `objectType: 'iframe'`, in combination with the `src` variable.
Use this in the `plotOptions`:

```
series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
        events: {
            click: function () {
                var name = this.category;
                var url = '../Graphics/VtnPopup.aspx?cat=' + name;
                hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                    pageOrigin: {
                        x: 50, // this.pageX, will open the popup on top of each column
                        y: 50 // this.pageY will open the popup on top of each column
                    },
                    objectType: 'iframe',
                    src: url,
                    headingText: name
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh I see, well that works perfect. Thanks, you made my day :D. Just one more question, how can I change the width and height to 100% to cover all the screen?

Comment: Sorry - I didn’t see your follow-up question earlier. Please see this Highslide demo page for how to create a full width/height iframe popup: http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/full-size-popup.html

Comment: Thanks, I used: 
var sW = $(window).width()-50; 
var sH =  $(window).height()-50; 
and set that in width and height.